Solved: how can I avoid unintended New Lines with customWidgetBuilder in flutter_widget_from_html_core?
I have a problem with the flutter_widget_from_html_core plugin when I use customWidgetBuilder. When I add the custom tag to my HTML and use customWidgetBuilder to build a custom widget with that tag, it adds a new line before and after the widget.
my code is:
               HtmlWidget(qBox1ContentHtmlCopy,
                  customWidgetBuilder: (element) {
                    bool containHole = true;
                    int hole = 0;
                    String counter = "";
                    while (containHole) {
                      hole++;
                      counter = hole.toString();
                      if (!qBox1ContentHtmlCopy.contains("wahid$counter")) {
                        containHole = false;
                      } else if (element.localName == "wahid$counter") {
                        return const Text(
                          'TEST',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  renderMode: RenderMode.column,
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14,),
                ),

qBox1ContentHtmlCopy contains the below HTML data:

but the Output Of the code is:

How can I resolve this?
Solved:
Finally, I found the solution by using InlineCustomWidget:
return const InlineCustomWidget( 
             child: Text('TEST',
               style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 20,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
             ),
           ),
        );

